# Test Android org.json without using the emulator?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, console-application

I am learning to program to android and would like to do some code that use the org.json.JSONObject
But running the emulator is so slow.
Are there a way to test it thru console only?

On IOS we have the Playground. Are there something like that for Android?

Answer (score 1):

Enable developer option in your Android mobile or tablet. run your code directly your device via usb debug or tcp connect.

Comment: You mean a real android device?